# Activating the Dual NIC of the Intel 82575 PCI Controller, Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I have installed the PCI Dual Nic with the Intel 82575 chipset.  This card is recognized, and the igb driver assigned to it, but only one of the interfaces becomes active.

How do I configure the driver to recognize both of the Interfaces?

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82575EB Gigabit Network Connection (rev 02)
02:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82575EB Gigabit Network Connection (rev 02)
```

---

```
ethtool -i enp2s0f1
driver: igb
version: 5.4.0-k
firmware-version: 1.115, 0x87850000
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:02:00.1
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: yes
```

---

```
ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:d5:5e:b1:12:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp2s0f0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1520 qdisc mq master br0 state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6c:b3:11:32:3e:d4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp2s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1520 qdisc mq master br0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6c:b3:11:32:3e:d5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1520 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6c:b3:11:32:3e:d4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

---

Any suggestions on where to troubleshoot would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: APologies this is the Intel 82575 chipset.

Comment: What's the output of `ip link show`?

Comment: The ifconfig shows NIC0 is active NIC 1 is not.  Is this what you mean?  Otherwise, please explain ip link.

Comment: It would be great if you could add the output of `ip link show` to your question.

Comment: OK, will get that.

Comment: Hi Thomas, it appears that after booting the desktop, enp2s0f0 is down.  ifup enp2s0f0 does not help.

ifup enp2s0f0
Unknown interface enp2s0f0

Comment: Status is down.

Comment: Hm...so it looks like both interfaces `enp2s0f0` and `enp2s0f1` are configured in a bridge `br0`. Not sure if that is what you want to achieve. Is there a cable plugged in the second NIC and does have a working end on a switch? Maybe bad cable?

Comment: Yes, both interfaces are configured in a Bridge. but the bridge cannot operate without both interfaces.  I have tried multiple cables, multiple ports, swapping cables, but always have only one interface active.

Comment: I can trouble shoot to the driver.  I have even replaced the card with a new one, but still have the same results.  I only have one PCI interface.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Automatic fail-over or both ports active at the same time?

Comment: I would like both ports active at the same time.  That's a requirement of having a bridge.  (input to output)